# Excel Power Pivot: calculations with filtered subtotal as a column as source for calculated column

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I've got data that looks like this:

```
year    channel discount    sales
2015    1       3.00        20,000
2015    1       3.00        23,000
2015    2       3.00        67,000
2015    1       6.00        80,000
2015    1       9.00        40,000
2016    1       4.00        98,000
2016    1       7.00        34,000
2016    1       7.00        15,000
2016    2       7.00        45,000
2016    1       10.00       60,000
2017    1       4.50        54,000
2017    1       7.50        60,000
2017    1       10.50       50,000
2017    2       10.50       54,568
```

I would like to use power pivot to group by `year` and calculate the weighted sales like this: The discount should be multiplied by the sales associated with it, then divided by the total sales per year.

In Powerpivot, I calculate my total sales in the column by
`TOTAL_SALES_YEAR=CALCULATE(SUM([sales]), ALLEXCEPT(Sheet1,Sheet1[year]))` and my weighted sales as `WEIGHTED_SALES=[discount]*[sales]/[TOTAL_SALES_YEAR]`.

**Now, however, I would like for my total sales to react to filters** - whether channel 1, channel 2, or both are selected.

All channels: Subtotals are calculated correctly
[image: All channels: Subtotals are calculated correctly]

Filtered channel: Subtotals have not changed
[image: Filtered channel: Subtotals have not changed]

How can I go about this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using the `ALLEXCEPT` function, you are stripping the filter context for everything except the `[year]` column. If you want to preserve the `[channel]` filter context, then you can add it as a column inside the function as well:

```
= CALCULATE(SUM([sales]), ALLEXCEPT(Sheet1, Sheet1[year], Sheet1[channel]))
```

Another way to do this is instead of specifying what filter context to keep, you can specify which filter context to remove. It looks like you want to remove the `[discount]` filter context:

```
= CALCULATE(SUM([sales]), ALL(Sheet1[discount]))
```

---

**Edit:** It appears that you did your formulas as calculated columns rather than as measures. If you want the table to be responsive to filters, then you need to use measures.

Notice in my screenshot that the measures have "fx" next to them and the pivot table columns are not labeled with "Average of" or "Sum of" aggregation descriptions.

Your weighted sales measure will also have to change a bit to something like this:

```
= SUMX(Sheet1, Sheet1[discount]*Sheet1[sales]) / [TotalSales]
```

[image: Measures]

Comment: thank you for your answer. If I input this formula, I get an error `A circular dependency was detected: 'Sheet1'[TOTAL_SALES_YEAR],'Sheet1'[TOTAL_SALES_YEAR],'Sheet1'[WEIGHTED_SALES],'Sheet1'[WEIGHTED_SALES],'Sheet1'[TOTAL_SALES_YEAR].`. However, I don't want to remove any filter context - even discount filters should be applied. The reason I added the `ALLEXCEPT` was to have a sum column aggregated by year. Note that TOTAL_SALES_YEAR is equal to the subtotal of each year. Now I would like for that subtotal to adjust to (any) filters; i.e. having 163,000 for 2015 instead of 230,000 in ex.2.

Comment: @s-heins This is because you created these as calculated columns rather than measures. Please see my edit.